# How to implement two finger tap using hammer.js

Tags: jquery, ios, safari, hammer.js

I am trying to implement two finger tap using hammer.js on iOS Safari but don't have any success. As I understand if both the finger touches in span of little difference even 50ms it triggers pinch gesture.

With tap event I am checking `event.gesture.touches.length === 2` it satisfy my requirement but its efficiency is very low.

Can you please help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Fingers.js lib (https://github.com/paztis/fingers.js)
Two fingers tap is explained in example pages.
You can customize the number of fingers you want (1, 2, ..., even 11)

Comment: for the time being I used another solution...but whenever I will get time...will try this!! Thanks :)

Comment: using another library is not really an answer to the question on how to do it with hammerjs.

@abhas would you mind sharing your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add a tap recognizer with the parameter "pointers" set to 2. Depending on how your code is organized there's more than one way to configure it. e.g.

```
var hammer = new Hammer.Manager(div, {
        recognizers: [
            // RecognizerClass, [options], [recognizeWith, ...], [requireFailure, ...]
            [Hammer.Tap, { event: 'singletap2', pointers: 2 } ],
            [Hammer.Tap, { event: 'singletap' } ],
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('pad');
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement);
mc.add( new Hammer.Swipe({ event: 'a', pointers: 2,direction:2}) );


mc.on("a", function(ev) {
   alert("left 2")
});
```

You can use the above code to know left swipe with 2 fingers.

> Change **pointer** value to change **number of fingers**.

To change the swipe direction use below table.

- DIRECTION_NONE   **1**
- DIRECTION_LEFT   **2**
- DIRECTION_RIGHT  **4**
- DIRECTION_UP     **8**
- DIRECTION_DOWN   **16**
- DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL     **6**
- DIRECTION_VERTICAL   **24**
- DIRECTION_ALL    **30**